# Two template classes with methods calling each other

Tags: c++, templates

Two template classes have two methods each which call the other class's method:

```
// Foo.h
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    static void call_bar() {
        Bar<int>::method();
    }

    static void method() {
        // some code
    }
};

// Bar.h
template<typename T>
class Bar {
public:
    static void call_foo() {
        Foo<int>::method();
    }

    static void method() {
        // some code
    }
};
```

How can I get this to work? Simply adding `#include "Bar.h"` to Foo.h (or vice versa) doesn't work because each class needs the other one.

EDIT: I also tried forward declarations, but it still fails at linking stage:

```
// Bar.h
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    static void method();
};

// Foo.h
template <typename T>
class Bar {
public:
    static void method();
};
```

Comment: Have you tried forward declaration https://stackoverflow.com/q/4757565/673826 ?

Comment: You just asked this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm sorry for the confusion but I realized that my problem is actually a bit different.

Comment: @mlt Yes, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have two class templates that are dependent on each other, using two .h files does not make sense. In order to be able to use `Foo`, you need both `Foo.h` and `Bar.h`. In order to be able to use `Bar`, you also need both `Foo.h` and `Bar.h`. It's best to put them in one .h file.

1. Define the classes.
2. Implement the member functions at the end.

---

FooBar.h:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
   public:
      static void call_bar();

      static void method() {
         // some code
      }
};

template<typename T>
class Bar {
   public:
      static void call_foo();

      static void method() {
         // some code
      }
};

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::call_bar() {
   Bar<int>::method();
}

template<typename T>
void Bar<T>::call_foo() {
   Foo<int>::method();
}
```